# .net 8 minimal api swagger Error in docker - uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Tags: swagger-ui, .net-8.0, minimal-apis

I have a .net 8 minimal API with swagger running OK in VS 2022 but when I containerize the app, I get a blank page when I try to access the swagger page.
Here's how I set up swagger:

[image]

Here's the exception I get when I try to access the swagger endpoint while running the app in a container:

[image]

And this is the code block refered to in the error:

[image]

The same code block when the app is run in VS 2022 has the configObject populated as below:

[image]

What I have tried:

1. I have tried setting `ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` and `ENV DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Development` when building the container image (and verified these are set when container is run).
2. I have also tried un-setting `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS` from the default 8080 for .net 8

So my question is, how do I get the swagger endpint to render correctly when running in docker?

Comment: Do you have a full [mre] (with docker file and command you use to run it)? Can you please post it somewhere like github?

Comment: No I don't, but could try. Just to add, even running the compiled app on the desktop (win 11) produces the same error. It's also an AOT build (haven't tried none AOT) so should be easily reproducible (I think).